# VS embed string in assembly opcodes

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly

I'm trying to write a hello world program in assembly in visual studio. I would like to have the string saved as opcodes between instructions like this

```
call label1
    "hello world"
label1:
    pop esi
    push esi
    call print
```

How can I do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: It would appear you can't: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx [unless you manage to set up the right sequence of instructions to form that string as instructions, but that can be hard for arbitrary strings]

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You're assuming inline assembly. That isn't necessarily a valid assumption.

Comment: @Mats Petersson Thanks.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf I am using inline assembly. Can I do it in some other way?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Is there any other way to achieve this in Visual Studio? Well, I suppose in Macro assembler, but most people don't even have one...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: yes, and on the contrary. :) yes, there are is a way in inline assembly, namely `_emit` (it's like a single value `DB`). and on the contrary, if you have Visual Studio with C++, then you also have the macro assembler, it's bundled, it's `ml.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With inline assembly you can use the `_emit` pseudo instruction, like this (here for 32-bit code):

```
auto foo()
    -> char const*
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, offset my_data
        jmp epilogue
    my_data:
        _emit 'H'
        _emit 'e'
        _emit 'l'
        _emit 'l'
        _emit 'o'
        _emit '!'
        _emit 0
    }
    epilogue: ;
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    wcout << foo() << endl;
}
```

I don't know of any way to write the strings as strings with inline assembly.

I recommend using proper full assembler instead. If you're using Visual Studio then you already have it installed, it's `ml.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

In inline assembler in Microsofts compiler, you can't do the obvious solution of

```
 db "hello world"
```

so you have to actually generate the instruction sequence that produces the right bytes:

From my hand-disassembly, this should do it - I have not CHECKED that this gives the right sequence

[It could perhaps be possible to do:

```
 __asm 
  {
    call label1
    _emit(0x68)
    _emit(0x6f) 
    ... // rest of "hello world"
  label1: 
      pop esi
      push esi
      call print
  }
```

I haven't got a Visual studio compiler to try it on. Not sure if it's happy to jump to a label in a different __asm section tho.]

```
PUSH 6f6c6c65h     ; push = 'h', 6f6c6c64 'ello'
AND  al,al         ; space
JA   6fh           ; ja = 77 = 'w', 6f = 'o' 
JB   6ch           ; JB = 72 = 'r', 6c = 'l'
FS: ADD AL,AL      ; fs = 64 = d, ADD AL, AL = 0
```

This is obviously very unpractical, and I would not do this for anything that needs maintenance... [And I have probably got something wrong, and I expect that `JA constant` and `JB constant` isn't valid in inline assembler, you have to jump to a label... Which means you need to have a label about 100-110 bytes forwards to make `'l'` and `'d'`

Comment: Well, this answer is wrong. I'll post a correct answer once I've completed my coffee & biscuits and a suitable little example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Better now? I don't think I've personally ever used `_emit`, but I remember someone making a preprocessor that translated 3DNow! instructions to _emit (or some such).

Comment: Well, as mentioned, the semicolon technique doesn't work. It's not a statement separator. And as far as I know there's no such for inline assembly, which means that it's practically impossible to generate the instructions via a C++ variadic macro. However, in full assembler they can be generated via text equivalent macro. But then, in full assembler the `_emit` isn't needed. Heh.